# Width 700px border html

Tags: html, css

How to make default with 700px included border 1px

```
<div class="body">

.body {
       width:700px;
       border: 1px solid blue; }
```

screen width = 702px

How to keep body width 700px

Comment: Setting a 698px width?

Comment: Go learn the basics of the _box model_, and meet https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yeahahabosstoldont. Add second div with border inside body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

It specifies that elements should have padding and border included in the element's total width and height.